# Titanium: register to system events

Tags: javascript, dom-events, titanium-mobile, systemevent

I'm looking for a way to create custom events on Titanium.
In order to do that I would need to register to a global var array every time the window opens (not a problem) however, I would have to un-register every time the window is cleaned from the memory, the event that fires then is the `E/TiBaseActivity(10448): (main) Layout cleanup`.
I would like to register to that event with a un-register function for the specific window.

Is there a way to do that?

---

*Update:*

Well, I got an answer on the [Titanium Q&A](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/131149/register-to-layout-cleanup-event#comment-111590).

Apparently there is a `close` event that will fire everytime the window is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, I got an answer on the [Titanium Q&A](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/131149/register-to-layout-cleanup-event#comment-111590).

apparently there is a close event that will fire everytime the window is closed.